# Error with VTD XML finding ghost / non existent paths

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I have a block of XML as follows with the 3 included attachmentBinary elements (albeit truncated for readability):

```
  <MyRequest>
      <MojNumber>219</MojNumber>
      <AttachmentBinary fileExtension="image/jpeg">/9j/4UK8RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAAAoAAAEBBAABAAAAAAABABAgAJAAAApgAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAsAAAABsBBQABAAAgAAADEBAgAOAAAAwAAAADIBAgAUAAAAzgAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBA</AttachmentBinary>                                   
      <AttachmentBinary fileExtension="image/jpeg">/9j/4UE1RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAAAoAAAEBBAABAAAAAA5QCMg7udvGabszG8hX5M5JZhk/SrFvuV0Q7dmx87s4c8LUlwrRqrKWyBl</AttachmentBinary>
      <AttachmentBinary fileExtension="image/jpeg">/9j/4SfRRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAAAoAAAEBBAABAAAAAASTwcU+GZSThd3y4J6GpAm8ysxDmQALk71A9hVKTvcznHS5gSh2LSgkEgyG</AttachmentBinary>
      </MyRequest>
```

My VTD-XML Java code to first extract the fileExtension and the main Base64 encoded jpg is as follows:

```
try {
                        ap.selectXPath("/MyRequest/AttachmentBinary/text()");
                    } catch (XPathParseException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }

                int i = 0;

                while ((i = ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
                    // i points to text node of
                        String ext  = vn.toString(vn.getAttrVal("fileExtension"));
                     System.out.println("ext is:"+ ext);

                     String s = vn.toRawString(i);
}
```

I am however getting 6 rather than 3 hits. Out of these only 3 yield viewable images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xpath asks for a text node which has no attribute node... so you should use `/MyRequest/AttachmentBinary`, that is without text()... then ext will be alright...

but to get the text() you need to call getText() and make sure it is not -1.